# How to create a CanvasView object

Tags: java, android, canvas

I got a class CanvasView :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.Random;




public class CanvasView extends View {


    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint paint;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    Random random = new Random();


    public CanvasView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        initPaint();    //here i just create my Paint      
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }



    public void drawRandom() {
        canvas.drawCircle(random.nextInt(700), random.nextInt(700), random.nextInt(200), paint);

    }
}
```

Then i try to create CanvasView object in another activity like this:

```
 canvasView = new CanvasView(this,null);
```

and then i try to call method drawRandom()

```
  canvasView.drawRandom();
```

then happens error:`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)' on a null object reference`

i know that it means that canvas=null at this moment but how to fix it?I tried a lot but still cant do it.

Dont blame me if this question is as stupid,as me, i am beginner,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        initPaint();    //here i just create my Paint
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        canvas.drawCircle(random.nextInt(700), random.nextInt(700), random.nextInt(200), paint);
    }

    public void drawRandom() {
        invalidate();
    }
```

BTW, don't forget to add it to window after New CanvasView().
Like this:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup =(ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        viewGroup.addView(canvasView);
```